# MongoDB collection not listed in _schema

Tags: mongodb, schema

I am using MongoDB 2.6 standard.  I have successfully created multiple collections, inserted data, queried data, etc.  Works fine inside of the Mongo shell, as well as from NodeJS apps using MongoSkin.  So far, so good. Now I need to use a third-party tool (D2RQ) to access the data. It appears that D2RQ uses the _schema collection to obtain collection names, column names, data types, and so on.  D2RQ works for three of the collections because the collections are in _schema in MongoDB.  A fourth collection is not in _schema and seems to be invisible.  However, the fourth collection is present in MongoDB.  The collection has data.  I can query the collection in the Mongo shell, and from NodeJS using Mongoskin.  Any idea why the collection is not appearing in _schema?  Is this a MongoDB bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a MongoDB bug.  The root cause of the problem is that D2RQ uses the UnityJDBC driver to access MongoDB.  There is a parameter on the JDBC connection string indicating whether or not to rebuild _schema.  D2RQ does not properly pass the parameter when making the JDBC connection to MongoDB, resulting in the _schema collection being out of date on all calls after the first call.  The solution has two parts:

Part one was to write a tiny NodeJS application that does nothing but force the _schema rebuild on connection.  That solved my immediate issue.

Part two was to then extend the tiny NodeJS application to be a full featured export process that generates an RDF file from MongoDB.  This allowed me to remove both D2RQ and the UnityJDBC driver from the solution stack.

"The most reliable component in the architecture is the one that is not present"